# Module vs DynamicModule for a dynamic variables in a grid. || Spelling Bee

Tags: dynamic

When my daughter asked me help with her spelling homework, for me the obvious thing to do was to write a *Mathematica* program for it.

The words:

```
words = {"lightning", "thunder", "cloudy"};
```

The code:

```
Grid[
 Module[{x = 0, t = 0},
    {
     #,
     Button["Start", t = Hold@AbsoluteTime[] - AbsoluteTime[]], 
     Button[Style["\[Checkmark]", Darker@Green], t = ReleaseHold[t]; x++],
     Button[Style[    "\[Times]",        Red  ], t = ReleaseHold[t]; x--],
     Dynamic[x],
     Dynamic[Clock[]; ReleaseHold[t]]
     }
    ] & /@ words]
```

Which produces this output:

[image: screenshot]

So when I ask her a word, I click "start". Then I click ✔ or × if her answer is right or wrong respectively. I plan to keep track of time to answer, so the timer now shows how much time it took to answer.

So my question is: Why do I have to use `Module` instead of `DynamicModule`? For some reason the `Grid` command does not work if I use `DynamicModule`. On the other hand, if I use `Module` (as it is shown), then the syntax highlighter shows my "t" and "x" variables in red as if I am doing something wrong:
[image]

**Update:** I have just realized that using `Module` instead of `DynamicModule` is not a viable option as the scores are lost when you reopen the notebook.

**Update 2:** For the record, this is the finished program incorporating the advice from Mr.Wizard and kguler

```
DynamicModule[{x, t, status, h},
 x[_] = 0;
 t[_] = 0;
 status[_] = False;
 h[_] = {};
 Column[{Grid[
    MapIndexed[{
       #,
       Button["Start", 
              Speak@#; status[#2] = True; 
              t[#2] = Hold@AbsoluteTime[] -AbsoluteTime[], 
              Enabled -> Dynamic[! status[#2]]],
       Button[Style["\[Checkmark]", Darker@Green], 
              t[#2] = ReleaseHold[t[#2]]; x[#2]++; AppendTo[h[#2], t[#2]]; 
              status[#2] = False,
              Enabled -> Dynamic[status[#2]]],
       Button[Style["\[Times]", Red],
              t[#2] = ReleaseHold[t[#2]]; x[#2]--; AppendTo[h[#2], -t[#2]];
              status[#2] = False, 
              Enabled -> Dynamic[status[#2]]],
       Button["spell", Speak@StringJoin[Riffle[Characters[#], ","]]],
       Dynamic[x[#2]],
       Dynamic[Clock[]; ReleaseHold[NumberForm[t[#2], 2]]],
       Dynamic@
        If[Length@h[#2] > 0, 
         Module[{z = Transpose[{Abs[#], Sign[#]} & /@ h[#2]]}, 
          Graphics[
           (Rectangle @@@ 
            (Partition[{Accumulate[First@z],Last@z}\[Transpose],2,1,{2,2},{{0, 0}}] /.
             {{x1_, y1_Integer}, {x2_, y2_Integer}} -> {{x1 + 0.2, 0}, {x2, y2}})) /.
             {Rectangle[{x1_,0}, {x2_, 1}] -> {Darker@Green, Rectangle[{x1, 0}, {x2, 1}]}, 
              Rectangle[{x1_,0}, {x2_,-1}] -> {Red, Rectangle[{x1,0}, {x2, -1}]}},
           ImageSize -> {Automatic, 20}, 
           PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]], 
         ""
        ]
    } &, words],
    Alignment -> Left],
    Row[{Button[
      "reset", (x[{#}] = 0; t[{#}] = 0; h[{#}] = {}) & /@ 
       Range@Length@words], Spacer[10]}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You should really look at [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/)  (which of course doesn't mean that we shouldn't solve this in Mathematica!)

Comment: +1 for doing spelling homework using Mathematica!

Comment: +1. Using `Beep` is perhaps going too far, but ... `Speak` and `Characters` might come handy in this task: `Speak["potatoes"]` and `StringJoin[Riffle[Characters["potatoes"], " "]]`.

Comment: I happened to glance at this again and I noticed that you did not localize pattern names with `RuleDelayed`.  For example `Rectangle[{x1_,0}, {x2_,-1}] -> {Red, Rectangle[{x1,0}, {x2, -1}]` should be written `Rectangle[{x1_,0}, {x2_,-1}] :> {Red, Rectangle[{x1,0}, {x2, -1}]` to protect `x1` and `x2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the object created by `DynamicModule` does not actually evaluate until it is displayed, therefore `Grid` has nothing to format other than the outer list.

```
words = {"lightning", "lightning", "cloudy"};

dynlist = 
  DynamicModule[{x = 0, t = 0},
    {
     #,
     Button["Start", t = Hold@AbsoluteTime[] - AbsoluteTime[]], 
     Button[Style["\[Checkmark]", Darker@Green], t = ReleaseHold[t]; x++],
     Button[Style[    "\[Times]",        Red  ], t = ReleaseHold[t]; x--],
     Dynamic[x],
     Dynamic[Clock[]; ReleaseHold[t]]
     }
    ] & /@ words;


ToString[ dynlist[[1]] ]
```

> "DynamicModule[{x = 0, t = 0}, {lightning, Button[Start, t = \
>   Hold[AbsoluteTime[]] - AbsoluteTime[]], Button[[Checkmark], t = \
>   ReleaseHold[t]; x++], Button[[Times], t = ReleaseHold[t]; x--], \
>   Dynamic[x], Dynamic[Clock[]; ReleaseHold[t]]}, DynamicModuleValues :>
>   \ {}]"

You could build the rows inside the module:

```
Column[
 DynamicModule[{x = 0, t = 0},
    Grid@{{
     #,
     Button["Start", t = Hold@AbsoluteTime[] - AbsoluteTime[]], 
     Button[Style["\[Checkmark]", Darker@Green], t = ReleaseHold[t]; x++],
     Button[Style[    "\[Times]",        Red  ], t = ReleaseHold[t]; x--],
     Dynamic[x],
     Dynamic[Clock[]; ReleaseHold[t]]
     }}
    ] & /@ words]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Addressing your comment you could move the map operation inside Grid like this:

```
DynamicModule[{x, t},
 x[_] = 0;
 t[_] = 0;
 Grid[
  MapIndexed[
    {#, Button["Start", t[#2] = Hold@AbsoluteTime[] - AbsoluteTime[]], 
     Button[Style["\[Checkmark]", Darker@Green], 
      t[#2] = ReleaseHold[t[#2]]; x[#2]++], 
     Button[Style["\[Times]", Red], t[#2] = ReleaseHold[t[#2]]; 
      x[#2]--], Dynamic[x[#2]], 
     Dynamic[Clock[]; ReleaseHold[t[#2]]]} &,
   words
]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be on a grid. Otherwise it looks ugly as you have shown.

Comment: @Gustavo see edit; sorry for sloppy formatting but I don't have time to make it pretty.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried unsuccessfully with `Map`, but I see you cleverly solved it using `MapIndexed`.