# Basic question about Dynamic

Tags: dynamic

Please consider the following:

```
InputField[Dynamic[X1], Number, Alignment -> Center];
InputField[Dynamic[X2], Number, Alignment -> Center];
Slider[Dynamic[Y1], {0, 200, 1}];
Slider[Dynamic[Y2], {0, 200, 1}];
Dynamic[FK, Dynamic[X1*(1 + Y1/100)]];
Dynamic[MK, Dynamic[X2*(1 + Y2/100)]];
Dynamic[HK, Dynamic[FK + MK]];
HeadTest = NumberQ[#] & /@ {X1, X2, Y1, Y2, FK, MK, HK}
```

Why would `FK`,`MK` and `HK` not have the head `Number`? (I guess I just did not understand how to use `Dynamic` and `DynamicModule`.)

Comment: You do not need to create a pure function (`# &`) to `Map` (`/@`) an existing one:  `NumberQ[#] & /@` is not needed, `NumberQ /@` will suffice.

Comment: Related: [(1864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1864/121), [(2972)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2972/121), [(5817)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any beginner these are a must:

- [**Introduction to Dynamic**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html)
- [**Advanced Dynamic Functionality**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html)

Because for your code as it is right now, with no additional definitions, those variables are symbols - you did not define them numerically (`Dynamic` got nothing to do with it).

```
X1 // Head
```

> Symbol

Now if you do this you'll get your 'Number':

```
{X1, X2, Y1, Y2, FK, MK, HK} = Range[7];
InputField[Dynamic[X1], Number, Alignment -> Center];
InputField[Dynamic[X2], Number, Alignment -> Center];
Slider[Dynamic[Y1], {0, 200, 1}];
Slider[Dynamic[Y2], {0, 200, 1}];
Dynamic[FK, Dynamic[X1*(1 + Y1/100)]];
Dynamic[MK, Dynamic[X2*(1 + Y2/100)]];
Dynamic[HK, Dynamic[FK + MK]];
HeadTest = NumberQ[#] & /@ {X1, X2, Y1, Y2, FK, MK, HK}
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

I am not sure what you trying to get, but **generally the price of dynamic updating is change of `Head`**. Maybe this example will help to understand - turn your attention to what changes, what evaluates and what does not:

```
{Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x], x, Dynamic[x] // Head, x // Head, 
 Sin[x], Sin[Dynamic@x], Dynamic@Sin[x]}
```

[image]

Comment: "...generally the price of dynamic updating is change of Head."  Great insight into and explanation for how to think about dynamic updating.  +1

Comment: Vitaliy, thanks for identifying the duplicate.  Please vote to close the new question as such.

Comment: Vitaliy, we get this question often enough that I believe it needs to be added to the [pitfalls post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/121).  You have the best reviewed answers here on the subject.  Would you be willing to write one?  If you do please also include whatever part of [John Fultz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1581155/618728) seem appropriate, with attribution.  If you do not wish to do this I will try my best.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would appreciate if you could write this. And yes John's answer of course is super.

Comment: Okay, I'll try.  When you see it come up (perhaps not tonight) please review and correct it as needed.