# Input field that appends to a list

Tags: inputfield

I'd like to make a dynamic, changeable list, which has elements that are supplied by the user in an InputField.

I want the program to have an InputField and a "reset" button. Every time the user types an element into the InputField and presses TAB, this element is added to the list. The list is reset to the empty list when clicking on the "reset" button.

Is this possible in *Mathematica*? The reset part seems easy, but the first part seems difficult. Perhaps should I use a second button, "add element"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track value changes with `Dynamic@Refresh` and `TrackedSymbols`

```
list = {};

DynamicModule[{x}, Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[x], String], 
   Dynamic@Refresh[If[x != "", AppendTo[list, x]; x = "";]; "", TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
    Button["Reset", list = {}]
   }]]

Dynamic[list]
```

[image: value changes]

It works with TAB and Enter.

For numbers:

```
list = {};

DynamicModule[{x}, Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[x], Number], 
   Dynamic@Refresh[If[x != Null, AppendTo[list, x]; x = Null;]; "", TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
    Button["Reset", list = {}]
   }]]

Dynamic[list]
```

**Edit:** It works in V7!

Comment: I don't at first see why this works with Tab, but it does, and in v7 as you say. +1 :-)

Comment: I see now!  It was my use of `Row` that was messing things up.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: it probably should be mentioned that it is just by accident that this will work with Tab. With Tab the input is submitted and focus is moved to the next "focusable" input element. Only if there is no other such element as here focus will be reset to the same element. If you have e.g. another `InputField` in the same cell, the focus will move to that. For the exact specification of the OP of course that doesn't matter...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: it seems that an additional `Deploy` would make your version with `Row` instead of `Grid` also work. I'm not sure whether that is intended, version dependent or documented...

Answer (score 5):

*Edit:* Now works with either <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, thanks to [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov).

Now simplified with your own idea to use `Null` as the `Dynamic` variable:

```
list = {};

Dynamic[list]

Grid@{{InputField[Dynamic[Null, AppendTo[list, #] &]], Button["Reset", list = {}]}}
```

Type expressions, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and watch them appear in `list` (as viewed with `Dynamic`).

Note that with either form you will get a `Null` in the list with a blank entry, and this has nothing to do with `Null` within the code.  The documentation says:

> For expressions, a blank input field is taken to have value `Null`. For strings, it is taken to have value `""`.

If this is a problem you could use:

```
InputField[Dynamic[Null, If[# =!= Null, AppendTo[list, #]] &]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! When I enter x into the InputField, list gives Null, even if I delete the part "x = Null" from your code. Why is that?
What does this part of the code "x = Null" mean?
Thanks!

Comment: Even this, could we change the Dynamic part by this:
InputField[Dynamic[Null, AppendTo[list, #] &]]
This seems to work on my side, but I didn't know we could use Null as variable of Dynamic. Is that normal behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel Since we are using the second parameter of `Dynamic` I think it is save to use `Null` as you did.  I'm going to add that to my answer.  Great idea!

Comment: Ok, great! I have read the documentation about the second parameter of Dynamic, but that's not enough helpful for me. Is there any other resource on the net/in books about Dynamic functionality of Mathematica? Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel Please see the documentation links in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9551/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your answer completely covers my. I forget  the second parameter of `Dynamic`. I just want to add that `Column` insstead of `Row` will allow TAB.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wizard for your help!

Comment: @ybeltukov That was a great addition; thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job!

To see the changes as you add number to the list or reset it evaluate `Dynamic@val` in the notebook. Its output will let you see what is happening with the list `val` when you are using the following interface.

```
val = {};
Row[{
  DynamicModule[{y},
   EventHandler[
    InputField[Dynamic@y, Number, ContinuousAction -> True, 
     FieldHint -> "Enter Number"],
    {{"KeyDown", "\t"} :> (val = Append[val, Setting@y]; Clear[y])}]
   ],
  Button["Reset List", val = {}]
  }, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

Comment: This apparently doesn't work in v7, even with out `FieldHint -> "Enter Number"`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that is a unexpected limitation then! Have got no access to v7. If you can correct it for v7 feel free to do so :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I just tried this with version 7.0.1 and it seems to work alright (without the `FieldHint` of course). What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: @PlatoManiac: your use of `Block` is to my understanding not doing anything, especially it doesn't really localize `y` in any relevant way. Most probably you meant to use `DynamicModule` instead. It would probably also be more conventional to clear the input field with `y=Null` instead of `Clear[y]`, but that is more a matter of taste. Other than that I like that your solution unlike the others should work independent on what else is contained in the gui, so +1 anyway...

Comment: @AlbertRetey You are absolutely right about the `Block`. I missed it somehow. I updated that part. Thx!

Comment: @PlatoManiac: you're welcome. Another advantage of that approach is that you could also do the reset of the list with a keyboard shortcut by adding another rule to the `EventHandler`, e.g. `"EscapeKeyDown":>(val={};y=Null;)`. Using `"ReturnKeyDown"` instead (or together) with the tab key might also make the interface more convenient to use (IMHO the desired behaviour is an abuse of the tab key event, but well...)