# Removing an extra curly braces when using Grid with an If statment

Tags: manipulate, grid-layouts

I use `Grid` to align controls in Manipulate. Here is a simple example

```
Grid[{
     {name1,Control2,value1},
     {name2,Control1,value2}
    }]
```

The 3 fields above come out aligned automatically, even when one field, such as name, is longer than another, and `Spacing` can be used to control field width for all controls at once.

A problem shows up when I need to use an `If` statement to build controls based on selection used in previous control:

```
Grid[{
     {name1,Control2,value1},

     (*now make a control based on above value*)

     {Dynamic[If[name1==1,
                 {name2,Control1,value2},
                 {name3,Control3,value3}
                ]
             ]
     }
    }]
```

This works well, and allows me to change the controls that appear on the UI based on a selection that was made in another control but the problem with the above is that it gives an extra set of `{}` coming out from inside the `If` needed grouping which ends up messing up the alignment.

I think I need to use `Sequence` or some other function to remove the inner `{}` but can't figure the syntax.

I made below a simple working code to illustrate

```
Manipulate[
 eq,

 Grid[{

   {"eq", SetterBar[Dynamic[eq], {1, 2}], Dynamic[eq]},

   {Dynamic[If[eq == 1,

      {"v1",
       Manipulator[Dynamic[v1, {v1 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}],
       Dynamic[v1]
       },

      {"v2",
       Manipulator[Dynamic[v2, {v2 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}],
       Dynamic[v2]
       }
      ]], SpanFromLeft
    }}
  ],

 {{eq, 1}, None},
 {{v1, 1}, None},
 {{v2, 1}, None}
 ]
```

which gives

[image]

You can see that the whole expression was treated as if I wrote

```
Grid[{
     {name1,Control2,value1},
     {{name2,Control1,value2}}
    }]
```

I tried using `First`, `Sequence` but can't get it to come out correct.

Again, I need to keep the 3 fields in each `Row` separate and in a List. I can't just use `Row` since it means each row will collapse to become one field, not three fields, and I lost the alignment I needed, i.e. I can't just write

```
Manipulate[
 eq,

 Grid[{

   {"eq", SetterBar[Dynamic[eq], {1, 2}], Dynamic[eq]},

   {
    Dynamic[If[eq == 1,

      Row[{"v1",
        Manipulator[Dynamic[v1, {v1 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}],
        Dynamic[v1]
        }],

      Row[{"v2",
        Manipulator[Dynamic[v2, {v2 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}],
        Dynamic[v2]
        }]
      ]], SpanFromLeft
    }
   }

  ],

 {{eq, 1}, None},
 {{v1, 1}, None},
 {{v2, 1}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

Any idea how to make the above work and remove those extra `{}`?

**edit**

Let me just clarify why using `Row` as a solution does not work.

Compare the following 2 examples

```
Manipulate[eq,

 Grid[{
   {"eq", SetterBar[Dynamic[eq], {1, 2}], Dynamic[eq]},

   {Dynamic[If[eq == 1,

     Row[{"v1", Manipulator[Dynamic[v1, {v1 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}],Dynamic[v1]}],

     Row[{"v2", Manipulator[Dynamic[v2, {v2 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], Dynamic[v2]}]
    ]]
   }

   }],

 {{eq, 1}, None},
 {{v1, 1}, None},
 {{v2, 1}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

We can see that the whole `Row` was treated as one field. I want to the above to come out *as if* I have written this

```
Manipulate[eq,

 Grid[{
   {"eq", SetterBar[Dynamic[eq], {1, 2}], Dynamic[eq]},

   {"v1", Manipulator[Dynamic[v1, {v1 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}],Dynamic[v1]}

   }],

 {{eq, 1}, None},
 {{v1, 1}, None},
 {{v2, 1}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

You see the difference? This is the important part. thanks.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1864/121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work as you need?

```
  Manipulate[eq, Dynamic@Grid[{{"eq", SetterBar[Dynamic[eq], {1, 2}], 
  Dynamic[eq]}, {If[eq == 1,
    {"v1", Manipulator[Dynamic[v1, {v1 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], Dynamic[v1]}, 
    {"v2", Manipulator[Dynamic[v2, {v2 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], 
       Dynamic[v2]}], SpanFromLeft} /. 
      (lst : {x_String, _, _}) :>  Sequence @@ lst}], 
   {{eq, 1}, None}, {{v1, 1}, None}, {{v2, 1},  None}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, instead of post-processing, you can define a custom `if` that "holds" sequence arguments as follows:

```
 ifSeqHold = Function[{test, arg1, arg2}, 
    If[test, Sequence @@ arg1, Sequence @@ arg2], HoldAllComplete];

 Manipulate[eq,  Dynamic@Grid[{{"eq", SetterBar[Dynamic[eq], {1, 2}], 
 Dynamic[eq]}, {ifSeqHold[ eq == 1, 
   {"v1", Manipulator[Dynamic[v1, {v1 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], Dynamic[v1]}, 
   {"v2", Manipulator[Dynamic[v2, {v2 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], 
   Dynamic[v2]}], SpanFromLeft}}], 
   {{eq, 1}, None}, {{v1, 1}, None}, {{v2, 1}, None}]
```

which gives the same result.

Update: `Hold[Sequence@@{...}]` followed by `ReleaseHold` also works:

```
  Manipulate[eq, Dynamic@Grid[{{"eq", SetterBar[Dynamic[eq], {1, 2}], 
    Dynamic[eq]}, {If[eq == 1, 
     Hold[Sequence @@ {"v1", Manipulator[Dynamic[v1, {v1 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], 
      Dynamic[v1]}], 
     Hold[Sequence @@ {"v2",  Manipulator[Dynamic[v2, {v2 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], 
      Dynamic[v2]}]]// ReleaseHold, SpanFromLeft} }], 
   {{eq, 1},  None}, {{v1, 1}, None}, {{v2, 1}, None}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's use a `Column` of `Row`s rather than a `Grid`.

```
Manipulate[eq,
 Column[{
   Row[{"eq", SetterBar[Dynamic[eq], {1, 2}], Dynamic[eq]},
    StringJoin@@Table[" ",{52}]],    
   Dynamic[If[eq == 1,
      Row[{"v1", Manipulator[Dynamic[v1, {v1 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], 
        Dynamic[v1]}, "   "],
      Row[{"v2", Manipulator[Dynamic[v2, {v2 = #} &], {0, 2, .1}], 
        Dynamic[v2]}, "   "]
      ]
     ]   
   }],
 {{eq, 1}, None},
 {{v1, 1}, None},
 {{v2, 1}, None}
]
```

[image]

I do think that the use of spaces to format is a bit hacky; I'm not certain how it will look across platforms.  There might be a better way to do it - perhaps use of `Pane` or `Panel` or `Spacings` or `Margins` or I don't know what.  I think the basic idea is there, though.