# Why doesn't Quantity accept a Dynamic expression as a second argument?

Tags: front-end, dynamic

If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm using the following code with the intent of using controls to easily input values and units:

```
Slider[Dynamic[b]]
SetterBar[Dynamic[lengthUnit], {"feet", "inches", "centimeters", "meters"}]
Quantity[Dynamic[b], Dynamic[lengthUnit]]
```

The above code returns "Quantity[0.,feet]"

But if I leave Dynamic out of the second argument by substituting the following line, everything works as expected:

```
Quantity[Dynamic[b], lengthUnit]
```

I suspect that this has something to do with the `HoldRest` attribute of `Quantity` and the `HoldFirst` attribute of `Dynamic`, but I'm not sure. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to make this work?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Related:  [(1864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1864/121), [(2972)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2972/121), [(5817)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/121), [(9550)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9550/121).  Of these this may be a duplicate: [(2972)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2972/121)

Comment: Cross posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/491037

Answer (score 5):

Let's try to explain this: The `Dynamic` never goes away and just because you don't see it on screen, doesn't mean that it isn't still there. So let's assume you have a similar function which doesn't act in such a special way as `Dynamic` does and let's call it `freakyFunc`. This function has no definition and when you use it, it is not further evaluated.

The question is now, what do you expect as result when you call

```
Quantity[freakyFunc[1], freakyFunc["feet"]]
(* Quantity[freakyFunc[1], freakyFunc["feet"]] *)
```

or when you call something like

```
Plot[freakyFunc[a] x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Right, it just won't work because you cannot calculate or plot something, when you have this `freakyFunc` wrapped around an expression in the wrong place.

But let's assume that `freakyFunc` will evaluate everything that you give as argument, which is the usual behavior anyway:

```
a = 1;
freakyFunc[a]
(* freakyFunc[1] *)
```

Nothing spectacular so far. Now, we will give `freakyFunc` a very important meaning: It will only *display* its arguments when you call it, but it will stay there, invisible but alive. Furthermore, when you call something like `freakyFunc[a]`, then it will display the *value* of `a` and track all chances of `a` from now on.

If you have followed me so far, it should become obvious that `freakyFunc` inside your `Quantity` won't work. Instead, you want the whole `Quantity` expression tracked and dynamically updated. So let's try this with `Dynamic`, because if you understood `freakyFunc`, then you understood how `Dynamic` works *in general*:

```
Slider[Dynamic[b]]
SetterBar[
 Dynamic[lengthUnit], {"feet", "inches", "centimeters", "meters"}]
Dynamic[Quantity[b, lengthUnit]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And of course you see now, that you have to dynamically update the whole `Plot` instead of the function only

```
Slider[Dynamic[a], {1, 5}]
Dynamic[Plot[a x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}]]
```

There are limits and exceptions to my explanation, but it should help you to get on the right track. Btw, one of those exceptions is that options of functions can have (often, always, rarely, I don't know) dynamic content on their right side. Therefore, this works

```
Slider[Dynamic[a], {1, 5}]
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> Dynamic[a]]
```

Comment: Dynamic[Quantity[Dynamic[b], lengthUnit]] works also and Dynamic[b] still in the background.

Comment: @Algohi It depends on how you define *works*, because when you try to add two quantities, the result is not what one expects: `Dynamic[Quantity[Dynamic[b], "feet"] + Quantity[1, "meters"]]` Now try the same with a version where you remove the inner `Dynamic`.

Comment: yes, it is now clear. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

A control such as slider is updating a variable and the front-end needs to know that the variable is dynamic, so the Dynamic wrapper goes on the variable. But `Quantity` is a display form and the front-end only needs to know that it should treat the whole form as dynamic.

On my system, V10.1 running on OS X Yosemite,

```
Quantity[Dynamic[b], lengthUnit]
```

does not work. Selecting a new unit from setter bar is**not*** reflected in the `Quantity` display. However,

```
Quantity[Dynamic[b], Dynamic[lengthUnit]]
```

does work, but really all you need is one `Dynamic`:

```
Dynamic @ Quantity[b, lengthUnit]
```